How to Convert docx to pdf with special characters like tick marks and cross mark in linux
I am working on my project, where I come across a problem when I am trying to convert my docs document to pdf. When I am trying to convert docs into pdf in linux special character convert in different character as you can see in example.

This is Docs
[]
(https://i.sstatic.net/2fKRaE4M.png) After conversion in pdf.
I am using following code to convert docs into pdf.


Please never ever add a code like this , the editor is very nice to show the code in a decent way.

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

One of the major problems with a format like PDF was it was designed to be faithful across "devices" and had many ways to do that before Unicode enforced unique numbering. Thus we have /WinAnsiEncoding and /MacAnsiEncoding producing variations with the same numbering.
So the numbers for binary characters in early PDF 1.# terminology, i.e. current versions, are NOT UTF-8 but multiple other ranges.
Your source DOCs are using these Windows device Numbers
char(251)char(252)char(253)char(254)char(255) 
These mathematically are identical to lower single bytes
\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFE\xFF
And in another font those will be û ü ý þ ÿ
Thus the answer is clear the wrong font was applied or not available on a non Windows device.
There is no "programming" failure, the failure is not using the designed source program (MS Word) on the Windows OS. 
If using a Mac the characters would be from this range.
Characters on the Mac are usually different than Windows because Windows used the ISO Latin-1 Character Set and the Mac uses the Roman character set.
Solution may be to see if UTF-16 works so
✗ = <2717> or <2718> = ✘ and ✓ = <2713> or <2714> = ✔
